# Establish websocket connection on a shared hosting?

Tags: php, websocket

I'm working on a `php` `websocket` chat app and everything's working fine, but the problem is I went to a hosting company to get a hosting plan and after I've uploaded my app `websocket` didn't worked because I didn't find a way to run `server.php` file.

> On my local machine, I was able to run `server.php` file from the terminal.

What I wanna know that, Is there any way to create a `php` file **act** like `server.php`?

Comment: With shared hosting you likely won't be able to run a socket server. They usually only allow access over web ports (80 and 443) and you won't have access to listen on those (else you would be listening to everyone on the shared host).

Comment: @Jonathan Web sockets are a protocol that run over HTTP, and listen on `80` and `443`.  It's entirely possible to have an upstream proxy that is listening for a whole host and forwarding requests downstream.  This is commonly done.  The network side of things isn't the problem here.

Comment: @Brad Sure it is. With shared hosting at least. I mean I guess you could have shared hosting that allows you to listen on some higher port that they proxy requests to, but most shared hosting (php especially) is you just putting your code on a pre-built server along with a thousand other websites. There isn't the option to listen downstream to anything as they are likely using some sort of vhost to just switch the document root based on the website requested. If you were able to listen to port 80/443 on shared hosting, that would be a pretty big security hole.

Comment: @Jonathan I get what you're saying.  I'm referring to your comment about the issue not being able to listen to port `80` or `443`.  I'm pointing out that this isn't the problem.  Vhost configuration works just as well with WebSockets as it does static files.

Comment: @brad They wouldn't be able to listen to ports 80/443 simply because it is shared hosting. That would at least require sudo access which they won't have. So yes, they can't listen there. When I say "access", I mean "permissions". Not that the protocol won't work.

Comment: @Jonathan Sure, and I'm saying that it doesn't matter whether they do or not, as a vhost configuration on a shared host can be easily set up to point to the websocket application.  It doesn't even have to be a TCP socket.

Comment: @Brad Correct. I guess it's just been so long that I have used shared hosting (pre web-sockets) that I wouldn't even assume that was something they offered. Especially if it were php (I could understand node maybe). I would just assume that it was some sort of simple lamp stack. They could ask the host if this is possible. I imagine that any host that offered for anyone to run their own socket server would have a lot of long running processes bogging everything down so much that it would affect every site on the system.

Answer (score 0):

You need server hosting with access to shell/bash console. This is usually unavailable on shared ones. The basic hosting that would allow you to run this is a VPS or advanced a dedicated one.

But with VPS you might run into problems with hosting company if your script takes too much resources or the VPS instance is configured so that it will kill 'lingering' processes (depends on VM and configuration).